# Measures of central tendency and dispersion of multimodal distributions

Tags: mean, standard-deviation, descriptive-statistics, multimodality

I want to make the argument that the mean is not an optimal description of the central tendency of a multimodal distribution and neither is the standard deviation an optimal measure of the dispersion of a multimodal distribution.  A citation to a published article would be really helpful.  Or, a discussion of whether it even makes sense to try to measure the central tendency and dispersion of a multimodal distribution.  I have thousands of multimodal gaussian mixture distributions, and I know the mean, sd and weight of each component.  I want to say that the mean and SD of the component with the maximum weight is a more valid estimate.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "more valid"?  How are you measuring validity?

Comment: Good question.  I guess what I am really asking is: Is the central tendency of a multimodal distribution a reasonably thing to try to estimate with a single statistic (e.g, mean) and is the dispersion of a multimodal distribution a reasonably thing to try and measure by a single statistic and does the SD make sense in this regard.  I know that the percentage cutoffs for 1/2/3 SDs will not be the same as for a unimodal normal distribution.  That is one issue. Are there advantages to using only the mean (and SD) of the maximum Gaussian component as opposed to the entire distribution.